# Not able to apply css to two different tables

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I wanted to create two tables with different styles

I have used two classes and named them differently but after coding for css
either css is not working or the same css style is getting applied for both tables.

Ex: if i set a border-line to the first table, it gets applied to the other table too.

[The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aBve.jpg)

Comment: please share the code in a code snippet

Comment: You write a style for `th`and`td` that it doesn't have table class before it. if you want different style for `td` and `th`, use this `table.ssc th,table.ssc td{}` and `table.hsc th,table.hsc td{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table.ssc table,th,td {
  properties...
}
```

The "th" and "td" selectors you are targeting are not specific, that is why styles are getting applied to both the table. Here you can be more specific about the selectors like

```
.ssc td,
.ssc th,
.ssc.table {}

.hsc td,
.hsc th,
.hsc.table {}
```

Hope this helps